# Angular Local storage passing multiple values

Tags: angular, typescript, local-storage

I am using `Angular Local Storage` in my project. In `localStorage.setItem` I am trying to store multiple values as 2nd parameter

Eg - Instead of storing `rec` as 2nd argument

```
localStorage.setItem('Data', JSON.stringify(rec));
```

I want to store following values. How can I achieve this?

```
 this.firstName = data!.data2;
 this.middleName = data!.data3;
 this.lastName = data!.data1;
```

Below is my function

```
updateTheAmazonFields(rec: Data, new_value: HTMLTableDataCellElement) {
  const { data1, data2, data3} = rec;
  this.records.replaceAndGetNewRec({target_ui, data1, data3, data2}).subscribe(data => {
  this.processIncomingRecord(data);

// want to store following values
      this.firstName = data!.data2;
      this.middleName = data!.data3;
      this.lastName = data!.data1;


  localStorage.setItem('Data', JSON.stringify(rec)); ---->>>>> Here


  })
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
localStorage.setItem('data_1', JSON.stringify(this.firstName));
localStorage.setItem('data_2', JSON.stringify(this.middleName));
localStorage.setItem('data_3', JSON.stringify(this.lastName));
```

Comment: I am not getting any error, there is no data. I am using localstorage for back button functionality. When I press back button previous data is empty

Comment: That's strange. Have you tried logging the data on the console in order to check whether the data is retrieved properly from the backend?

Comment: Yes data is being retrieved , just checking the logs

Answer (score 0):

So, the local storage saves the key/value pair. You don't want to change the key instead store an object with a key. This is what you should do:

```
const data = {
              firstName: this.firstName, 
              middleName: this.middleName,
              lastName: this.lastName
              }
localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(data));
```

Everytime you will set an Item with this key the data will be replaced with new one. Using getItem, you can get the values:

```
const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('key'));
console.log(data.firstName);
```